# How does one return the pixel coordinates (or position) of a label in Google Vision API's label detection in Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, object-detection, vision-api

I can run label detection on an image using the Vision API. However, I want to know the coordinates of where that label was detected. For example, if a circle is detected somewhere in the image, how do I return the center of that circle in the Vision API?

The following is what was returned when I ran label detection on a local image of an ellipse. What is returned does not include x,y coordinates of the detected objects like text detection has:

```
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/01vkl
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Circle
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.8125786
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.8125786
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/03scnj
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Line
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.7547606
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.7547606
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/03g09t
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Clip art
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.68722004
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.68722004
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.mid : /m/06g58b
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.description : Oval
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.score : 0.60591185
google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.topicality : 0.60591185
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving the coordinates of a certain label it's not an option to consider because, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels), labels can identify general objects, locations, activities, etc. 
This means that the labels are not specifically set into a certain position, they are obtained from the whole context of the image.

However, there are some labels that correspond to certain objects (for example, using this [image](https://cdn130.picsart.com/299525913231211.png), you will see that there is the label 'cat' and also the object 'cat', [you can test it using the API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22gcsImageUri%22%3A%22%22%2C%22imageUri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn130.picsart.com%2F299525913231211.png%22%7D%7D%2C%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22OBJECT_LOCALIZATION%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22LABEL_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D)). So, you can run Object and Label detection over the same image and merge the results seeking for labels that correspond to objects.